# Log a request when it uses the virtual host file or .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, logging, virtualhost

I am having an issue with directoryIndex currently. I am trying to see if my .htaccess file and virtual hosts file are being hit correctly. Is there a way I can log something when a  request uses the .htaccess file or virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup individual log files for all virtual hosts. That gives you a clear destinction which server has been queried. You do that by repeating the logfile configuration options for each virtual host inside its configuration file.

.htaccess is different: what is logged depends on the modules used in there. So for example you can have mod_rewrite log all steps for debugging purpose by using configuration options from that module. In this case `RewriteLog` and `RewritelogLevel`. Check the modules documentation sites for details.